# Minimum over Probability Measures

Tags: measure-theory, polynomials, probability-distributions, optimization, sums-of-squares

Let $f$ and $g$ be polynomials in $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$.  Let $X$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$.  Finally, Let $\mathcal M(X)$ be the set of probability measures over $X$.

Can the optimization problem

\begin{equation}
\inf_{P\in \mathcal M(X)} \left ( \int f \ dP\right )^2 - \left ( \int g \ dP\right )^2
\end{equation}

be expressed exclusively in terms of the polynomials $f$ and $g$, without reference to the measure $P$?

For example, my hunch is that the above optimization problem is equivalent to

\begin{equation}
\min_{\mathbf x \in X} f(\mathbf x)^2 - g(\mathbf x)^2,
\end{equation}

but I don't know how to prove this.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $n=1$, $X=\{-1,1\}$,  $f(x)=x$,  and $g(x)=0$. Then the infimum equals $0$, whereas the minimum equals $1$.

Comment: Ah, of course.  Thank you for the counter-example.  I'm a little embarrassed that I didn't think of that.  I realize that all of my efforts to construct a counter-example have assumed a convex $X$.  What do you think, Alex: do the two optimization problems give me the same optimal value if $X$ is convex?

Answer (score 1):

You could think of Problem 2 instead as $\min_{P \in \mathcal M(X)} \int [f^2 - g^2] dP$. This has the same value as the original problem; the objective function is linear in the control ($P$), so there will be a solution on the boundary, i.e. a degenerate distribution.

Then write $\phi = f+g$ and $\psi = f - g$ and factor,

- Problem 1: $\min_P \int \phi~ dP \cdot \int \psi dP$.
- Problem 2: $\min_P \int\phi \psi ~dP$

So for example if either $\phi$ or $\psi$ crosses $0$, then Problem 1 has value $\leq 0$, whereas if $\phi \psi$ crosses $0$ then Problem 2 has value $\leq 0$. You could say more by looking at cases.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in, John.  Just to make sure I understand: is a "degenerate distribution" the same as a "Dirac distribution", where all of the probability is concentrated on a single point?

Comment: Yep, that's the one.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain the inequalities either. Say a function takes values a > 0 and - b < 0 at two different points, and consider a probability that only puts weight on those two points, p on the first and 1-p on the second. Then solve p a - (1- p)b = 0, you get p = b/(a+b) which is a well-defined probability. This gives a bound for the first problem which could be useful