# Nonnegative Polynomials Imply Nonnegative Probability Measure Product?

Tags: measure-theory, polynomials, probability-distributions, optimization, sums-of-squares

Let $f$ and $g$ be polynomials over $\mathbb R^n$.  Let $X \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a compact, convex set (a polyhedron, specifically, if that makes a difference).

Is the following true?

**Claim**:
If $f(\mathbf x) g(\mathbf x) \geq 0$ for all $\mathbf x \in X$, then

\begin{equation}
\left ( \int_X f dP \right ) \left (\int_X g dP \right ) \geq 0 
\end{equation}
for all probability measures $P$ over the set $X$.

Comment: This question is closely connected to another: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2492414/minimum-over-probability-measures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $f(x) = (x+2)x(x-1)$, $g(x) = -f(-x)$ on $X=[-1,1]$.

Then $f(x)g(x) \ge 0$, but with $P= {1 \over 2} m$ (that is, half the Lebesgue measure) we have $\int f dP = {1 \over 3}, \int g dP= - {1 \over 3}$.